# Fastest way to loop through all posts?

Tags: plugins, posts, loop

I need to run a background process in a plugin that does some work on ALL the posts in a person's database once the plugin is installed. I'm very new at working with wordpress so my research has shown that I can use the wp query or I can use "the loop".

Since I'm going through absolutely every single post speed is of the essence. I need to check the title, body, categories, meta tags, publish state and password protected. So based on this, which one of these would be fastest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The Loop" is just a name given to the `while (have_posts()): the_post();` loop used to iterate over an array of posts returned by `WP_Query()`. The other function used for querying posts is the get_posts() function, which returns a simple (non-extended) array which you can loop through with a `foreach` loop.

I don't think it matters a whole lot; however, if you're nitpicking, the `get_posts()` method is slightly faster and less memory-intensive, since it doesn't call `setup_postdata()` (which populates the template tags, etc.) on every post it loops through.

Either way, you're probably going to run out of memory on some setups with thousands of posts... Make sure you build in fallbacks in that case.

Comment: aaah... how do I explicitly deallocate memory after finishing with a given post?

Comment: looking at the codex API it seems there's an 'offset' and 'numberposts'. I can use this to only go through 100 at a time right? If so, that would solve the memory issue through garbage collection? Or are things cached in memory : / ?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not totally sure. Unset each of the local variables you're using before looping on to the next post. Call `ini_set('max_execution_time', $somehugenumber);` before starting. And include some kind of progress indicator to discourage user interrupt. Or break your task into chunks and run it as scheduled cron events.

Comment: Yes, you can use 'offset' to go through your posts in reasonable-sized chunks. That way you're only fetching an array of a specified size into memory. The get_posts array returns all the columns in the `wp_posts` table, so calling `get_posts('numberposts=-1')` on a site with 10000 posts loads into memory an array including the full post content from all 10000 posts. That would be the memory issue...

Comment: @Thirlan: Many functions that do something with a post will call `get_post()`, [which will add the post to the cache](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/post.php#L371). So even if you do multiple database queries for a single HTTP request, not all memory will be reclaimed. I recommend you do this with multiple requests (via Ajax, with a progressbar for feedback?), where each request processes a number of posts.

Comment: Implemented, tested, problem solved and answer accepted! Though I've come to find now that wordpress plugins have some major issues with handling low-touch background tasks  ¬_¬ My ultimate solution was to break up the job into "100 posts" batches that fire off with the "shutdown" hook. Meanwhile the thirdparty server pokes your site to speed the process up. This sounds quirky but the objective of the plugin is to be as user friendly, hassle free and automated as possible, so forcing the user to press a "sync" button after activating the plugin was deemed unacceptable and a waste of a click.

Answer (score 0):

"The loop" is just a name applied to a foreach loop applied to a WP_Query object.
So you need both. Typically the loop also includes the_post() so that you can use template tags.

There's another option though, that may be faster. Depending on what you need to do, you *could* do a direct database query to retrieve just the fields you want to edit. But since you also need categories and meta tags it would be a complicated join. For easier updates and backward compatability, you may as well use the regular WP_Query.