# Question about custom plugin

Tags: loop, get-posts

I'm new to the WP and created a small plugin to display the last 10 posts from the category. I use it twice, to display the posts of the two categories on the page. At each post displayed image, title, category, and date. Plugin "Query monitor" reports that he makes 55 queries to the database. I thought it was too much and, for comparison, I downloaded the plug-in "Category Posts Widget" which is under the same conditions makes it much less database queries. What am I doing wrong? I took the information from the codex. Below is my cycle.

```
<div>
    <?php
    global $post;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'category__in' => array($instance['category_select'])
    );
    $cnews = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($cnews as $post) :
        setup_postdata($post);
        ?>

        // display two first posts in one css style

    <?php endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>

<?php
    global $post;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'offset' => 2,
        'posts_per_page' => 8,
        'category__in' => array($instance['category_select'])
    );
    $cnews = get_posts($args);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($cnews as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        if ($i == 0) {
            echo '<div">';
            echo '<ul>';
        }
    ?>

        // display eight next posts in other css style

        <?php
        $i++;
        if ($i == 2) {
            $i = 0;
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    if ($i > 0) {
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</ul>'
    ?>
```

Comment: Please [improve your question title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title). Summarize your specific problem, do not include the words "WordPress" or "question".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your `get_posts` to [**`WP_Query`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/).

You are making a lot of queries because you're running [**`setup_postdata`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/setup_postdata/) is running its own set of queries to get the post data from the posts you got through `get_posts`.

This can be avoided by using [**`WP_Query`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) instead.

Based on your code, you should have something like this when you change to WP_Query

```
<div>
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'category__in' => array( $instance['category_select'] )
    );
    $cnews = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $cnews->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $cnews->have_posts() ) : $cnews->the_post();
    ?>

        // display two first posts in one css style

    <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    ?>
</div>

<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'offset' => 2,
        'posts_per_page' => 8,
        'category__in' => array($instance['category_select'])
    );
    $cnews = new WP_Query( $args );
    $i = 0;
    if ( $cnews->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $cnews->have_posts() ) : $cnews->the_post();
        if ($i == 0) {
            echo '<div">';
            echo '<ul>';
        }
        ?>

        // display eight next posts in other css style

        <?php
        $i++;
        if ($i == 2) {
            $i = 0;
            echo '</div>';
        }
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    if ($i > 0) {
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</ul>'
?>
```

#### UPDATE

To reduce it to one query, you can do something like:

```
<div>
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'category__in' => array( $instance['category_select'] )
    );
    $cnews = new WP_Query( $args );
    $count = 1;
    $style = 'remaining-eight';
    if ( $cnews->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $cnews->have_posts() ) : $cnews->the_post();
        if ( in_array( $count, range(1,2) ) )
            $style = 'first-two';
    ?>
            <div class="<?php echo $style; ?>" >
                //post content in here
            </div>
    <?php
        $count++;
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    ?>
</div>
```

Then you can you style based on the selectors **first-two** and **remaining-eight**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the number of requests after WP_Query use has increased.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there will be a significant difference between `WP_Query` and `get_posts` as discussed in this answer: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/12878/75524 My hunch here is that the architecture of the script could be improved so that it's not making two separate queries. I would probably approach this by making a single query and sorting the categories from that. I'll try to post an answer with that approach.

Comment: @jami0821 I've updated the answer adding a second snippet that uses just one query

Comment: Tunji Ayoola  Thanks, it works and looks better than my version. But database queries almost the same amount as in my first embodiment. I use the version based on yours.